# Using jQuery Validate and trying to get the label highlighted when it's not valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

*(TLDR: See my edit towards the bottom)*

I'm using jQuery Validate and everything is setup and working for the validation piece. However I've got radio buttons that I'm trying to have their `label` get highlighted in `red` when the user has not selected an option from that group of radio buttons.

The validation works for the radio buttons, however I can't get the highlighting for the label to work properly.

I'm having two issues:

1. On initial page load it is invalid since the user hasn't pushed
   submit yet so with my current code the label shows up as red on the initial page load.
2. When the user clicks on a radio button, it isn't changing back to
   black.

My code:

```
    var rules = {
        rules: {
            RadioButton: { required: true },                
        },
        messages: {
            RadioButton: { required: "Please select an option" },                
        },
        highlight: function (input) {
            $(input).addClass("error");
        },
        unhighlight: function (input) {
            $(input).removeClass("error");
        },
        errorLabelContainer: "#errMessage",
        errorClass: "invalid-inputs",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.attr("id", "errMessage");
        }
    };

    $('#form').validate(rules);
```

The code below is what I've done with regards to highlighting or unhighlighting that label:

```
 var validator = $('#form').validate().check('#RadioButton');
            if (!validator) {               
    $('#form').find('div[id="label"]').addClass().css({ 'color': 'red' });
        }

    if (validator) {  
$('#form').find('div[id="label"]').addClass().css({ 'color': 'black' });
    }
```

With the above code, I know that `var validator` is working because it is returning `true` or `false` in the right scenarios when I paste that code in dev tools.

The HTML:

```
 <div class="label" id="label">Selection</div>
```

I'm trying to get `Selection` to become highlighted.

This is the code that has given me the closest results to what I'm trying to achieve but it's still not working. I've tried searching the [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/), Stack Overflow, and other resources. I've exhausted all of my options so I'm hoping someone here can help out.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I have made some progression...

In `rules` under `highlight:` I added this:

```
$('#form').find('div[id="label"]').addClass().css({ 'color': 'red' });
```

And under `unhighlight:` I added the same thing, however with `'color : 'black'`.

This is "sort of" working. I removed all of the code underneath `validator`.

It basically turns `red` if there is any error what-so-ever, and it also makes me click on the page before it will turn `red`. If I get rid of an error it immediately turns back to `black`.

I'm not entirely sure on how to target the specific `RadioButton` validation `rule` and only turn it `black` or `red` based on whether that has been validated or not. I'm also not sure why it is making me click on the page before it triggers that `Selection` text to turn `red`, yet it turns `black` immediately after something has been validated.

I've tried this:

```
if($('#RadioButton').valid() == false){ //Do the color change }
```

And the opposite for if it's `true`, but that seems to just crash the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by add this to the `highlight` and `unhighlight` fields:

```
if ($("#RadioButton").attr("class") === "error") {
        return $('#label').css({ 'color': 'red' });
   }
```

And then:

```
if ($("#RadioButton").attr("class") !== "error") {
        return $('#label').css({ 'color': 'black' });
   }
```

I figured this is the easiest approach... The validate plugin adds the error class to the element so why not just search for the element, grab the `class`, and compare if it equals what you want it to equal. Then, in this case, change the color of the elements label to `black`.

Answer (score 0):

First issue:

Use a variable which keeps track on whether the user interact with the form or not (dirty), I prefer doing it on click

Second issue:

```
$('#RadioButton').click(function() { } )
```

When the button gets clicked then evaluate the form.

And with the selection, because of IDs should be unique in `html5` you can simply do this:

```
$('#label').addClass('highlighted')
```